# How to ajax this dropdown php variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I simply don't get jquery or ajax.

I understand javascript just fine, but for some reason, I can't ajax through my head. 
I'm sorry I have to ask this, but can some help me, I just spent literally the last day trying to make this jquery/ajax work for this drop down box, been through a bunch of examples. Tried them. Don't work.

This is what I'd like.

- The below drop box to dynamically change a variable in php without a submit button.
- I would like to use only one file, a php file named single-event.php .
- then display $total php variable in that h2 everytime the drop down box is changed.

  ```
  <?php $cost = 10.00;?>

       <select id = "attendee" class='postform' onchange="Onchange(this)" >

                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="6">6</option>
                      <option value="7">7</option>
                      <option value="8">8</option>
                      <option value="9">9</option>
                      <option value="10">10</option>
       </select>
  <?php $total=$cost*$(drop_down_box_selected); ?>
  <h2>
       <?php _e('Submit a payment of $' . $total , 'pippin_stripe'); ?>
  </h2>
  ```

I normally wouldn't go this low and simply ask someone to do my work but I'm just sick of trying, this was the closest i got to anything i wanted, but discovered I NEED to convert the value to a php variable.

Please help, I'm basically pulling my hair(not really as I'm bald), tired and still have an entire different project that needs to be finished by Monday.

```
        <select id = "attendee" class='postform' onchange="Onchange(this)" >

            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>


          <script type="text/javascript">
                 var dropdown = document.getElementById("attendee");
                 function onCatChange() {
                 if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value != -1 ) {
                document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        var price = document.getElementById("hto").value
        var num = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        var total = price*num ;

dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
        </script>
```

Thank you to anyone who gives any help.

Comment: The only difference between AJAX and a standard HTML page with a form is that with AJAX you use javascript to communicate with the server and exchange data without causing a page refresh.  In your code when the selection changes you need to send data to the server without actually doing a form post.  This can be done either using the ActiveX MS control to perform the async operation or Jquery.

Comment: I've tried, jquery, I've tried jquery looking at a hundred different stack overflows, tutorials ,  how tos. and i cant for the life of me, get either a good understanding of it, nor can I get anything to show any indication of functioning, I so tired of it, can someone place show me how i would this.

Comment: What type of web server are you using?  And what is the setup OS on both client and server?

Comment: Try this for help http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Spatttern I tried this, and cloudflare i think?

Comment: what did you try?